# Is there any way to manipulate files located on disk via JavaScript or Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to develop little app that loads details from JSON and then manipulate files selected by user (these files are located on the local disk).

Is there any way to implement it in JavaScript, HTML5 or Chrome Extensions?

I've found solution using NPAPI, but that is too much effort for me (faster I'll make that app in Qt with Python, or Qt with C++...).

Cheers.

Comment: Not sure about chrome extension, but it's definitely impossible to access files via JS and HTML5 (without upload input). It would be huge security issue.

Comment: Local storage is accessible via Javascript in HTML5 as ScottE says; only works in Firefox and chrome.

Comment: @mozillanerd, can you post some links with examples, tutorials with usage localstorage? But please don't post the ones from html5rocks.

Comment: Here's one that I started reading just today: seems pretty easy: http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-three/

Comment: Good example from the standards organization. http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate files that were selected by user (through the file input and HTML5 File IO), but without [NPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397048/60462), you have no direct [r/w]-access to the filesystem (with an exception to HTML5 localStorage, which is a sandboxed environment within your extension).

Thus - depending on your requirements, a standalone app might be a better choice.