# Developing Chrome Extensions Using NPAPI in C++

Tags: c++, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a simple Chrome extension in C++, using NPAPI, which does the job of dumping the HTML content of the current page onto a file. I don't have much expertise in developing plugins/extensions. How do I get started on this?

Comment: The question has a bit of terminology confusion it in. You can't develop a Chrome extension in C++. You develop Chrome extensions in HTML and JS, and you can optionally have your extension bundle an NPAPI plugin that's written in C (or C++).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 - Create a Extension...
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

2 - Create a NPAPI plugin...
http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/

3 - On the manifest of your extension add the plugin...

```
"plugins": [
    { "path": "your_npapi_plugin.dll" }    
  ],
```

4 - On your extension background page create the plugin

```
<script>
var plugin = document.getElementById("MyNPAPIPluginId");
...
</script>
```

5 - Create a javascript that you will use as a content script injected on every page.
On that script communicate with your npapi scriptable object and do the work you want to do.

---

> How do I get the value of MyNPAPIPluginId? All I have is the name of the DLL?

On your background page when you add the tag of your plugin, you place the id

```
<embed type="application/my-plugin-mimetype" id="MyNPAPIPluginId">
```

On Windows you add the MIMEType on the resource file of the DLL, add a entry with:

```
VALUE "MIMEType", "application/my-plugin-mimetype"
```

Comment: How do I get the value of MyNPAPIPluginId? All I have is the name of the DLL.

Comment: On your background page when you add the tag of your plugin, you place the id <embed type="application/my-plugin-mimetype" id="MyNPAPIPluginId">

Comment: On Windows you add the MIMEType on the resource file of the DLL, add a entry with: VALUE "MIMEType", "application/my-plugin-mimetype"

Answer (score 4):

There's a plugin here that will help you....
http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/
...source is there aswell.  This plugin will allow you to write a string (your html) to a file plus a few other nice things.  Windows and Linux only unfortunately.
Then all you need to do is write a script to dump what you want.

As smorgan points out in the comments these sort of plugins have the potential to be rather dangerous.
So make sure when you add the plugin to your manifest that you set the public property to false...
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

```
 "plugins": [
    { "path": "plugin.dll", "public": false }
  ]
```

And in the future (Chrome 18) you should use manifest version 2...
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/manifestVersion.html

Also, I take it that you want to save the file without any user input.  If that isnt true and having a dialog to select where to save the file every time is acceptable then this can be done without using a plugin.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are not very, *very* careful with how you package and use this plugin, you give every web page in the world read/write access to every file on the computer of every user who installs your extension. An NPAPI plugin that allows arbitrary I/O is *extremely* dangerous, and needs to be handled accordingly.

Comment: Your completely right on that one, Ill update my answer a little.

Comment: It shall not make use of any I/O. I'm actually creating the web-capture plugin for Google Chrome, similar to the Adobe web-capture plugin for IE. The plugin should work on Windows and Mac and I'll be adding a DLL later. Is there anything I should take care of from the beginning?

Comment: Well I dont know jack really when it comes to making a plugin (its all a little beyond me), but one thing you might like to look at is FireBreath....  http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/

Comment: You are going to make an extension that writes a page to a file but doesn't do any file I/O? How does that work?

Comment: It shall do file I/O, but no user based I/O. Would that still be a security issue?

Comment: If you aren't very careful, yes; the problem is what pages do, not what users do. You need to make absolutely sure that pages can't use your plugin directly (the "public":false in the manifest) and that you don't expose any JS to pages that allows them to call into the NPAPI plugin to do arbitrary I/O. Ideally your NPAPI plugin should have as little capability as possible so that even if you do screw up and pages get access to the plugin, the damage is limited (for instance, make it only able to write files under a specific hard-coded directory, and don't allow it to read or delete files).

Comment: I do accept that the problem had a bit of terminology confusion in it (my apologies for that). I'm a newbie at making extensions/plugins. What I'm supposed to provide on Chrome is something similar to Adobe's Web-capture plugin/add-on (Convert to PDF, Append to Existing PDF, Smart Select, etc.) on Firefox and IE. Can this be done using a simple NPAPI plugin DLL (provided I have the required classes to do the conversion) with it's "public" set to false, and usage minimum, in the manifest?

Comment: @PAEz: How do I use the sample plugin you gave a link to (npapi-file-io)? I couldn't find any documentation on that link. I've downloaded the files and added as unpacked extension the folder that has the manifest.json file, but unable to figure out how do I use it.